# My web server refuse to set session or cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, nginx

i'm currently working with wordpress and plugins.

i created some plugin that really need a cookie and session to be stored on the server.
but when i try to set the session, it seems like my server refuse to store that session.

i did some test to prove that with this simple code.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if(isset($_SESSION['xjajal'])){
echo "SESSIOn nya : ".$_SESSION['xjajal'];

}else{

    echo "session belum ada..";
    $_SESSION['xjajal'] = "sssssjajal";

}

?>
```

and the result keep saying "session belum ada".
that mean (if im not wrong) the session are not stored.

my question is obvious, why this happen?
what thing could possibly causing this problem?

the very first thing that crossed in my mind is maybe becouse the server configuration that doesn't allow to accept session or permisson problem, but...
the wordpress, it's running very well. i could login and even "keep logged in". that mean sessions or even cookies from wordpress is stored very well. but why my sessions are not stored?

any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: don't do error_reporting/ini_set in your script. they should be set at the php.ini level so they're active during script startup. If there's a problem with session_start() (e.g. headers already sent), then you'll never see it because you don't turn on the debug options until AFTER you've tried starting the session.

Comment: Cookies are stored on the client and sent with each server request in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't support sessions by default. Use a specific plugin to handle sessions, eg. [WP Session Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/). Or use [WP_Object_Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache), if you want to store big data.